# Локализация сайта с помощью javascript. Как?

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью Javascript сделать локализацию сайта? Так чтобы нажимаешь на ссылку eng - сайт на английском, нажимаешь рус - на русском языке?

Comment: http://www.pvsm.ru/javascript/32383/print/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var localization = {
closeText = 'Закрыть', ...
}
```

Два таких файла, в одном на русском, в другом на английском.
При клике грузим этот файл. А там где названия - пользоваться этими переменными, что то вида:

```
localization.closeText
```